# T/SQL - Semi-manual Identity Column Insertion

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

**Initial Query**

```
DECLARE @Table1 TABLE (ID int, Value varchar(50))
DECLARE @Table2 TABLE (Value varchar(50))
DECLARE @MaxID1 int
DECLARE @MaxID2 int = 52

INSERT INTO @Table1 (ID, Value)
Values (1,'One'),(2,'Two'),(3,'Three'),(4,'Four'),(5,'Five')

INSERT INTO @Table2 (Value)
Values ('Six'),('Seven'),('Eight'),('Nine'),('Ten')

SELECT * FROM @Table1
SELECT * FROM @Table2
SELECT @MaxID1 = MAX(ID) FROM @Table1
SELECT @MaxID1 Scenario1, @MaxID2 Scenario2
```

**Expected Outcome of @Table1 after inserting values (Value field) from @Table2**

// *(Scenario #1 using @MaxID1)*

```
ID  Value
1   One
2   Two
3   Three
4   Four
5   Five
6   Six
7   Seven
8   Eight
9   Nine
10  Ten
```

// *(Scenario #2 using @MaxID2)*

```
ID  Value
1   One
2   Two
3   Three
4   Four
5   Five
52  Six
53  Seven
54  Eight
55  Nine
56  Ten
```

How do I semi-manually insert ID values into an Identity column (ID) while executing INSERT query on that table (@Table1) from another table (@Table2)? In the first scenario, I wish to take the Max(ID) from @Table1 and add 1 to it and keep adding records. In the second scenario, I wish to take a predefined # and then start adding a record where first new record's ID would be the predefined values and all subsequent new records would be Max(ID) + 1.

Thank you

UPDATED @Table 1 does NOT have identity constraint.

Comment: Discover [**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/)

Comment: lol...I used that for one of my post and a few folks "kindly complained" about me not posting the code...now ^^..lol

Comment: @user1569220 - Then mention in bold - code posted here/ what i tried - link. easy ?

Comment: @user1569220 Well, I didn't say substitute, just provide fiddle as well :)

Comment: Sry, still don't understand. Maybe somebody else see the connection between table1 and table2, and why 52 and not 42?

Comment: 2nd scenario output is based on MaxID2 var. So the first record that enters table1 has Id = MaxID2, 2nd record (MaxID2+1), 3rd record ((MaxID2+1)+1)..and so on.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to insert an arbitrary int value into an identity column, use IDENTITY_INSERT:

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [table_name] ON;
```

Only one table at a time for a given session can have this property on. Make sure you turn it off when done:

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [table_name] OFF;
```

Comment: Yep, but what kind of query do I add for the ID column to insert Max(ID) + 1? (not sure how to write it in words but maybe my expected output parts would be more helpful)

Comment: You can send the value from the client, or use a sequence object to keep counter, or have some homegrown solution. If it's just a one-time deal, you might even use a DBCC CHECKIDENT to reseed. What;s your usage scenario?

Comment: it's a pure sql query where I am inserting some "Value" fields from one table into another. The another table has an ID column. I need to add value into this ID column (MAX(iD)+1 for each record). This is usually a batch load (not one record "at a time"). 

SO it's INSERT INTO Table1 (ID, Value) SELECT {something},Value FROM Table2. I am trying to figure out exp for {something}

Comment: Would be best if you could provide the DDL and some sample data. Maybe use SQLFiddle?

Comment: What kind of query, other than what is posted in the main post, are you looking for? If you execute the SQL queries posted in the original post, it will give you sample tables. and then what I am trying to get out of inserting Table2 values into Table1 is listed under Expected outcome part of the post. Do you mean something else? I will figure out fiddle for temp variables and post that asap.

Comment: I don't see a connection between table1 and table2. Maybe something like this: INSERT @Table1 (ID, Value) SELECT MAX(ID)+1, 'Eleven'

Comment: Updated the main post. This should remove the confusion I caused in my question. sry.